# mask first k elements in a 3D tensor in PyTorch (different k for each row)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `M` of dimensions `[NxQxD]` and a 1d tensor of indices `idx` (of size `N`). I want to efficiently create a tensor `mask` of dimensions `[NxQxD]` such that `mask[i,j,k] = 1 iff j <= idx[i]`, i.e. I want to keep only the `idx[i]` first dimensions out of `Q` in the second dimension (dim=1) of `M`, for every row `i`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this can be done via a broadcasting trick:

```
mask_2d = torch.arange(Q)[None, :] < idx[:, None] #(N,Q)
mask_3d = mask[..., None] #(N,Q,1)
masked = mask.float() * data
```