# Mask the top k elements in a tensor in PyTorch (different k for each row)

Tags: pytorch

For any 2D tensor `X`, how to get the mask for `top K` elements for each row where `K` is a tensor (not restricted to an `int`)?

Input:

```
tensor([[0.6607, 0.1165, 0.0278, 0.1950],
        [0.0529, 0.4607, 0.2729, 0.2135],
        [0.3267, 0.0902, 0.4578, 0.1253]])
```

Desired output: for `K = torch.tensor([2,3,1])`

```
tensor([[ True,  False, False, True],
        [ False, True,  True,  True],
        [ False, False, True, False]])
```

I have tried these [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788412/mask-first-k-elements-in-a-3d-tensor-in-pytorch-different-k-for-each-row), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614116/how-to-get-top-k-elements-of-each-row-in-a-2d-tensor), but can not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `torch.topk` and `torch.tensor.scatter_` methods for this:

```
K = torch.tensor([2,3,1])
for idx, k in enumerate(K):
    top_k = torch.topk(x[idx], k)
    x[idx].scatter_(0, top_k.indices, 1)
mask = x.eq(1)
```